# Why is the vermin package in python causing a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax, package

I'm using Spyder, vermin is installed. In the Spyder console, I type:

`vermin test_script.py`

and the output is:

```
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20048/1234567890.py", line 1
    vermin test_script.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I fix what I'm doing? I get the same error whether I use absolute or relative path, or put the path in quotes.

Comment: That is a Python REPL, apparently. `SyntaxError` is an exception raised by the Python runtime. You meant to do that in a shell.

Comment: How would you recommend I write it from the shell? Then I get
```
'vermin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: sounds like you haven't installed `vermin` in a way that is being recognized with your shell. I am not familiar with that library, but it sounds like you are actually using a shell now

Comment: I've been using the Spyder console, in the python interpreter, and when I do pip install vermin, I get: "Requirement already satisfied: vermin in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.3.3)"

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10